# Difference between Text and String in Hadoop

Tags: string, text, hadoop

What is the difference between `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` and `java.lang.String` in the Hadoop framework?

Why couldn't they use `String` instead of introducing a new `Text` class?

I investigated the difference and found out it has to do with the encoding format; however I don't understand it yet.

Can someone explain the differences (with examples, if applicable)?

Comment: Main use of the Text class is it provides serialization and deserialization interface that helps when you send the data over network while string have limited functionality.In short it is string with extra functionality.

Comment: Have a look at here, with examples on differences.

http://javaonfingertips.blogspot.in/2016/01/difference-between-text-and-string.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The binary representation of a  Text object is a variable length integer containing
the number of bytes in the UTF-8 representation of the string, followed by the UTF-8
bytes themselves.

Text is a replacement for the  UTF8 class, which was deprecated
because it didn’t support strings whose encoding was over 32,767 bytes, and because
it used Java’s modified UTF-8.

Furthermore, Text uses standard UTF-8, which makes it potentially easier to inter operate with other tools that understand UTF-8.

Following are some of the differences in brief related to its functioning with respect to String:

**Indexing:**
Because of its emphasis on using standard UTF-8, there are some differences
between  Text and the Java  String class. Indexing for the  Text class is in terms of position in the encoded byte sequence, not the Unicode character in the string, or the Java
char code unit (as it is for  String).

For instance, `charAt()` returns an  int representing a Unicode code point, unlike the
String variant that returns a char.

**Iteration:**
Iterating over the Unicode characters in  Text is complicated by the use of byte
offsets for indexing, since you can’t just increment the index.

**Mutable:**
Another difference with String is that Text is mutable (like all Writable implementations in Hadoop, except NullWritable, which is a singleton). You can reuse a
Text instance by calling one of the set()methods on it.

**Resorting to String:**

Text doesn’t have as rich an API for manipulating strings as
`java.lang.String`, so in many cases, you need to convert the  Text object to a String.
This is done in the usual way, using the `toString()` method:

For more details read definitive guide.

Comment: How to convert `java.lang.String` to `Text` then?

Comment: Found it, `val t = new Text(s)`. btw, I am in Scala