# hadoop reducer member variable type

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Here is part of my MapReduce routine:

```
private static class Reducer ... {
    Text maxWord;
    private void reduce ... {
         some code to find the maximum word occurence;
    }

    private void combine ... {
         context.write(maxWord, ...);
    }
}
```

Somehow this works differently if I switch the type of the member variable `maxWord` from `Text` to `String` (also making a change `context.write(new Text(maxWord))` in the combiner. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "works differently"?

Comment: well, the output is different. I can post the whole code if you need.

Comment: I was just curious about it, I don't know the answer. Here you can find the difference between String and Text, but I don't get why it would change the output of your code, since it should be the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851665/difference-between-text-and-string-in-hadoop

Comment: turned out that the difference was coming from the fact that String is immutable and Text is mutable