# Using Hadoop Text Object toString() Method

Tags: hadoop, object-to-string

I understood the difference between String & Text.
[Difference between Text and String in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851665/difference-between-text-and-string-in-hadoop)

Question is If we are saying that String maximum storage size is 32767 bytes.

```
Text t = new Text("Hadoo... 2GB of content");
...
String c = t.toString();
```

How "c" will hold 2GB of data if it has size limitation?

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is no maximum storage of 32k on those classes, how is that problem for you?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut is right. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120002/is-there-any-limit-for-string-size-in-a-java-program

Comment: Thanks for the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of a Java String is not 32k bytes. It is the size needed to store `Integer.MAX_VALUE` characters, which is 2^31 - 1 (~2 Billion), which is around 4GB (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120002/is-there-any-limit-for-string-size-in-a-java-program)).

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851665/difference-between-text-and-string-in-hadoop) that you mention, refers to the size limit of the deprecated [UTF-8 class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/UTF8.html), not Java's String class.

Anyway, if you need so much space for a single Text instance, I would advise you to reconsider your algorithm. As Peter Lawrey says in the afforementioned post "I suspect all the works of J K Rowling would fit into one string."